# Replace missing data depending on values in specific column

Tags: r, missing-data

I have data structured as follows:

```
 X_PersonA  X_PersonB   Y_PersonA   Y_PersonB
 0          0           5           7
 0          5           3           0
 5          7           8           0
 0          0           1           2
 0          3           1           0
 9          0           0           0
 8          3           4           6
```

I have a data frame with indefinite variables as X and Y for two different people working together. I now need to replace some of the zeros with the following logic:
`X_PersonA = 0 AND X_PersonB = 0 -> both 0 = NA`
`X_Person A = 0 AND X_Person B ≠ 0 -> 0 stays 0`
`X_Person A ≠ 0 AND X_Person B = 0 -> 0 stays 0`

To be more precise, 0 only count as NAs if the related column also contains a 0. And I need the code to work for an indefinite amount of columns which can each be identified and follows the same pattern.

I appreciate any suggestions and hints!
Thank you very much!

Comment: `df[(df$X_PersonA==0 & df$X_PersonB==0),1:2]=NA` are you looking for this?

Comment: What about the `Y` variables?

Comment: If I adapt this function to my data, I get the follwing error:Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, (df$x_PersonA == 0 & df$x_PersonB ==  : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works with only variable-pairs, but maybe you can tweak this code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text =  "X_PersonA  X_PersonB   Y_PersonA   Y_PersonB
 0          0           5           7
 0          5           3           0
 5          7           8           0
 0          0           1           2
 0          3           1           0
 9          0           0           0
 8          3           4           6")

dat %>% 
        mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
        gather(key, value, -id) %>%
        separate(key, c("prefix", "person"), sep = "_") %>%
        spread(person, value) %>%
        arrange(id, prefix) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(ifelse(PersonA == 0 & PersonB == 0, NA, .)), -id, -prefix)  %>%
        gather(key, value, -id, -prefix) %>%
        mutate(origcol = sprintf("%s_%s", prefix, key)) %>%
        select(id, origcol, value) %>%
        spread(origcol, value) %>%
        select(-id)
```

The last 5 lines just backtransform the dplyr-table back to the (slightly awkward) format you've shown.

Result:

```
  X_PersonA X_PersonB Y_PersonA Y_PersonB
1        NA        NA         5         7
2         0         5         3         0
3         5         7         8         0
4        NA        NA         1         2
5         0         3         1         0
6         9         0        NA        NA
7         8         3         4         6
```

For each new pair X_PersonC - Y_PersonD you can add a new `mutate_each()` line (untested). How many pairs do you have?

If you have to perform *ternary* X_PersonA - Y_PersonB - Z_Person_C comparisons, or even more complicated checks, please find on your own solution.

Comment: No, it's always X_A vs. X_B checks - no ternary externsions. Thank you very much for your code, I will try it as soon as I can (hopefully tomorrow). The result looks just a I want it to - that's perfect.